# Pi as presentation tool (offline live polling)

Tags: server

I am looking for ways to use a pi as a standalone "player" for presentations. This would be easy enough, but I would like to add a possibility to host and display live polling. So the pi would offer the possibility to login all members of the audience  via wlan and fill out a poll hosted on the pi....
My general idea:

1) webserver on pi to run:
2) audience responce software on pi: https://danielausparis.github.io/mars/ 
3) QR-Code for login to webserver via pi´s wlan
3b) Audience logs into pi via wlan. (20-100)
4) pi sends results to beamer via hdmi
5) pi also supplies presentation via libreoffice

My current sticking points:

@2: will it run on a pi? Is an apache webserver sufficient?
@3b: Is that possible, or is it too much for the little raspi?

I am thankful for any support, especially regarding 2) and 3b)

Thanks for your interest, Stefan

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: It should work! The pi should be able to handle all that easily.